# Grade multiple forms on one spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I need to grade some google forms. Due to the way I needed it to work, I used one form for every question on the'quiz'. Not every person will have taken the same question. The responses are recorded into spreadsheets, but google makes each form have it's on sheet on the same document. So, because of the random questions, it make's it harder to grade. Some users may have all taken question 1, while only a couple have taken question 2. The names won't be in order, either, if they took the quiz at different times. So how can I grade this? There's about 40 questions total. I'm thinking I'll need to use google app script, but I'm not sure how.
[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q3EF0JJyJ60nmIaPy-UMgcCL85gjhprfaYfX0oR0bhc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: post a read copy of your consolidated spreadsheet.

Comment: Done. I should note I haven't sent the forms out yet, because of this issue. That's why the names are so generic

Comment: And where are the correct response to each question?

Comment: I added them on the 'answers' page

Comment: can you just use vlookup?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be to hard to do but might be a bit complicated to explain here...
What I would do :

- get all data from each page into an array
- add the question and the right answer in front of every user answer for each array row (page)
- concatenate all the arrays into one global array
- sort it on user Name and get a new array for each and every user
- sort all these arrays on question (it would probably be nice to add numbers to these question if you want to control the order of the questions)
- evaluate the user answers (easy since you have both the right answer and the user's answer in each row)
- write back to a spreadsheet, eventually one sheet / user

Nothing really hard to do but a lot of work though ;-)

Good luck

Comment: Would this work if I wanted to display each users score in a leaderboard on a google site?

Comment: Ok so I see what you're thinking, and I thought this might be done... it is a lot of work. Do you think it'd be easier to code this with GAS?

Comment: Sure...it will be easy because GS has dedicated methods to read and write to spreadsheets pretty easily. Give it a try and come back here if you have difficulties.